# AutoHotkey String concatenation with Object Properties

Tags: properties, autohotkey, string-concatenation

How does one concatenate strings in a Send command where one of the strings is in an objects property?

What I've tried:

```
obj = {prop: "hi"}
Send, Test %obj.prop% ; syntax error
Send, % "Test" % obj.prop ; syntax error
Send, Test %obj%.prop ; sends Test .prop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj := {prop: "hi"}
Send, % "Test " obj.prop
Send, % "Test " obj["prop"]
```

Steer away from using `=` as your assign operator, while it can be used to assign string or numeric value, it's better to develop habit of using `:=` (`Var := expression`) when it comes to autohotkey.

Comment: If I define obj using a class, how do I access class members?
...
class MyObj {
...
obj:=new MyObj("hi")
Send, "Test " obj.prop
...
prints out nothing